# Can't normally see result in wave (Modesim)

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, vivado

I have code designed for Vivid software. How I can translate this code into ModelSIM? In vivado, I should get the following values, but in modelsim I get completely different ones.
This is noise generator. Successful in adding pseudorandom noise sequence to our sine wave, but now we are trying to add Gaussian noise. The code and the simulation results for ADDITION OF PSEUDORANDOM NOISE SEQUENCE TO SINE WAVE IS GIVEN BELOW:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;  --try to use this library as much as possible.

entity sine_wave is
generic ( width : integer :=  4 ); 
port (clk :in  std_logic;
  random_num : out std_logic_vector (width-1 downto 0); 
  data_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)
  );
end sine_wave;

architecture Behavioral of sine_wave is
signal data_out1,rand_temp1,noisy_signal : integer;
signal noisy_signal1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
signal i : integer range 0 to 29:=0;
--type memory_type is array (0 to 29) of integer;
type memory_type is array (0 to 29) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
--ROM for storing the sine values generated by MATLAB.
signal sine : memory_type := ("01001101","01011101","01101100","01111010","10000111","10010000","10010111","10011010","10011010");
 --hi
begin

process(clk)
variable rand_temp : std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0):=(width-1 => '1',others => '0');
variable temp : std_logic := '0';
begin
  --to check the rising edge of the clock signal
if(rising_edge(clk)) then  

temp := rand_temp(width-1) xor rand_temp(width-2);
rand_temp(width-1 downto 1) := rand_temp(width-2 downto 0);
rand_temp(0) := temp;

--data_out <= sine(i);
i <= i+ 1;
if(i = 29) then
i <= 0;
end if;
end if;
data_out <= sine(i);
data_out1<=to_integer(unsigned(sine(i)));
random_num <= rand_temp;
rand_temp1<=to_integer(unsigned(rand_temp));
noisy_signal<=data_out1+rand_temp1;
noisy_signal1<= std_logic_vector(to_signed(noisy_signal,8));
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

[Vivado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVRxC.png)
[ModelSIM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyMYF.png)

Comment: `:=(width-1 => '1',others => '0');` IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.3 Array aggregates " A named association of an array aggregate is allowed to have a choice that is not locally static, or likewise a choice that is a null range, only if the aggregate includes a single element association and this element association has a single choice".

Comment: `signal sine` declaration, the initial value expression.14.4.2.5 Object declarations "If the object declaration includes an explicit initialization expression, then the initial value of the object is obtained by evaluating the expression. It is an error if the value of the expression does not belong to the subtype of the object; if the object is a composite object, then an implicit subtype conversion is first performed on the value ...". "A value is said to *belong to a subtype of a given type if it belongs to the type and satisfies the constraint;..." (5.1)

Comment: 5.3.2.2 Index constraints and discrete ranges An array value *satisfies* an index constraint if at each index position the array value and the index constraint have the same index range. This code should not successfully analyze (compile), elaborate (link) and simulate (load and execute) on either platform. The difference may relate to where and how the two tools get th values of the element types missing from the aggregates providing initial values. Both don't conform to the standard.

Comment: @user1155120 How can I run this code to get the results in the screenshot? I have just downloaded Verilog, but I get the same values as in the screenshot from the model sim.

Comment: Where's your testbench? In Modelsim your clock isn't even starting so you have some testbench problem.

Comment: Supply all 30 values to the initial value sine (your Modelsim waveform shows 28, the missing are X"2E", X"3D"). Provide an expression other than that aggregate for the initial value of rand_temp for a portable description. Provide a minimal reproducible example with a portable VHDL description so your readers can replicate your problem. VHDL is standardized despite Vivado or Modelsim allowing use of non-locally static choices in aggregates. As Brian notes you don't appear to be driving clk transitions(from the Vivado waveform appears to be around 30 clocks in 0.9 us).

Comment: There's a bounds check error during execution here `i <= i + 1;`  Put this as a statement in an else condition in the following if statement. It then simulates in a portable fashion, here with [ghdl and gtkwave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvfUu.jpg).